# How to download an excel file from a web icon with R

Tags: r, web-scraping, download

I'm currently trying to make R automatically download an xls file from the website: https://magallanesvalue.com/valores-liquidativos/

Basically there are a number of excel icons in the webpage that download an xls file when clicked. I've been trying to get the link of the download but it's been imposible. Basically the best I've manage to get has been trought the inspector of elements which leads to the following code:

```
id="historicalNAVEuropeanP" href="#"
```

I've already tried to read the htlm_nodes in order to find the xls link, but the `href="#"` only leads to the https://magallanesvalue.com/valores-liquidativos/ webpage again.

Any ideas at how to get the download links?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try a refresh on the page and download it again. I was able to download it all.

Comment: I'm trying to make R to download the files automatically, of course that I can dowload the files by simply clicking on them one by one, but thats precisely what i'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download first file:

```
url <- "https://magallanesvalue.com/wp-content/fund-datasheet/prices.php?fund=iberian&classLetter=M&from=20150109&to=20200328&type=EXCEL"
download.file(url, "file.xls")
```

For other files, you should change value for `fund=` and `classLetter=` (and probably `from=` and `to=` too)

Comment: Thank you very much Nurandi, that was exactly what I was looking for. Just out of curiosity, how did you manage to discover that link?

Comment: download file in browser, and then, copy link address

Comment: Wasn't aware of that, it'll be very usefull for other cases like this. Thanks again mate!